# PCA on MNIST works but validation data performs really bad

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I applied PCA on MNIST with a reduced dimensionality of 32. Then, to test it, I created a simple classification network. The train accuracy is good: `96%`, but on the other hand, the test accuracy is `2%`.

So what's wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np

(x,y),(x2,y2) = mnist.load_data()

y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y)  
y2 = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y2)  

def pca(x):
    x = np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], 784)).astype("float32") / 255.
    mean = x.mean(axis=1)
    #print(mean)
    #print(mean[:,None])
    x -= mean[:,None]
    
    s, u, v = tf.linalg.svd(x)
    s = tf.linalg.diag(s)
    
    k = 32 # DIM_REDUCED
    pca = tf.matmul(u[:,0:k], s[0:k,0:k])
    
    #print(pca)
    #print(pca.shape)
    return pca

x = pca(x)
x2 = pca(x2)

## BUILD A SUPER SIMPLE CLASSIFIC. NET
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation="relu", input_shape=(32,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam", metrics = ["acc"])

model.fit(x,y, epochs = 5, verbose = 1, batch_size = 64, validation_data = (x2,y2))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Epoch 5/5
60000/60000 [==============================] - 1s 23us/sample - loss: 0.1278 - acc: 0.9626 - val_loss: 11.0141 - val_acc: 0.0202
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are appling two differents "pca" for each set. The eigenvectors and eigenvalues of train can be different than test set.

Second, you are using SVD to obtain principal components, but this components is not the result that you want. Use principal axis like a projection matrix to obtain a better/compress representation of the data.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np

(x,y),(x2,y2) = mnist.load_data()

y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y)  
y2 = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y2)  

def pca(x):
    x = np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], 784)).astype("float32") / 255.
    mean = x.mean(axis=0)
    #print(mean)
    #print(mean[:,None])
    x -= mean[None, :]
    
    s, u, v = tf.linalg.svd(x)
    s = tf.linalg.diag(s)
    
    k = 32 # DIM_REDUCED
    projM = v[:, 0:k] #tf.matmul(u[:,0:k], s[0:k,0:k])  
    return mean, projM

def apply_pca(mean, projM, x):
    x = np.reshape(x, (x.shape[0], 784)).astype("float32") / 255.
    #print(mean)
    #print(mean[:,None])
    x -= mean[None, :]

    return tf.matmul(x, projM)
   
mean, projM = pca(x) 

x = apply_pca(mean, projM, x) 
x2 = apply_pca(mean, projM, x2) 

## BUILD A SUPER SIMPLE CLASSIFIC. NET
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation="relu", input_shape=(32,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = "adam", metrics = ["acc"])

model.fit(x,y, epochs = 5, verbose = 1, batch_size = 64, validation_data = (x2,y2))
```

Comment: I get this error with your code: `InvalidArgumentError: In[0] mismatch In[1] shape: 28 vs. 60000: [60000,28,28] [60000,32] 0 0 [Op:BatchMatMulV2] name: MatMul/`

Comment: Cause in the line: `x = tf.matmul(x, projM)`

Comment: Thank you! I'm still wondering, why do you pass the argument `mean` to function `apply_pca` when we assign a new value to the variable anyway? I guess we don't need to pass it.

Comment: My fault, I have also seen that you do the average for each sample. You should do the average in any case for each dimension. In the case of the MNIST your mean vector should be 28x28 (784). I've made some changes to make it work for you. All the pipeline that you do in training must always be the same in test: same mean, same projection, etc. For that reason we use the vector V instead of US.